# Safe Practice for Destructive Links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have links in my Rails 4 app that will allow a user to delete a booking. For example:

```
<%= link_to "Cancel this booking", guests_cancel_path(@booking), :confirm => "Are you sure you want to withdraw this booking?", :method => :patch %>
```

These links are shown conditionally in the view so if the booking is actually confirmed then they will see the link to cancel it in the view.

As I'm not too familiar with the workings behind PATCH so I would like to ask whether this approach is secure enough to stop other users creating this link and using it maliciously.

**Note** I have deliberately not provided access to this path via GET.

Comment: **Any** time you accept input to your app it needs to be validated on the server. You can't prevent anyone from posting or patching whatever data they want, so it's up to you how your controller handles this. Post your cancellation method if you would like us to look at that specifically.

Comment: Oh right - I didn't know whether it was possible to generate PATCH requests - no problem then. I will work on a layer of security in my controller.

Comment: so how would I access a controller action if it was only accessible via PATCH?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking as the developer, a regular user, or a malicious attacker?

Comment: never mind - I think I already know